# IBM Mobile first testing server using AWS (Amazon Web Service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-mobilefirst

**2 questions:**

**1) Do we need to purchase additional license to test mobile first on AWS?**

Currently we are using the free eclipse version for the developer to test on their own macbook.

At the moment, we need to setup a server for business users to test. So we are thinking of leveraging AWS (EC2) to setup a MobileFirst Server. However according to [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/), we need to purchse MobileFiest Server:

> This tutorial is intended for use with MobileFirst Server, which is available for purchase from IBM.

We have already purchase a license for the production server but not for the testing server.

**2) Which AMI (Amazon Machine Image) should we choose to run MobileFirst server?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Do we need to purchase additional license to test mobile first on AWS?

In order to install the MobileFirst Server on an external server (anything other than Eclipse), you must buy MobileFirst Platform Foundation from IBM.

> 2) Which AMI (Amazon Machine Image) should we choose to run MobileFirst server?

MobileFirst supports Linux in general, so you should be able to use any of those. Most popular I assume would be Ubuntu.

You may also want to check Amazon's community where users share images, and you may find there someone who shares an image for MobileFirst.

Comment: We have purchased MobileFirst Platform Foundation but it's only for the production server (physical). Currently we want another server on AWS solely for testing purposes. Do we need to purchase another license?

Comment: there is no real difference between a physical production server and a server in the cloud. Both are real physical servers. I don't think you need another license. If you have doubts, contact IBM.